# Getting an error:Unable to locate element: .ng-star-inserted when locating an element called ng-star-inserted in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm running the following code and getting the following error:

```
select_survey = browser.find_element_by_class_name("ng-star-inserted").click()
```

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .ng-star-inserted

this is the entire code:

```
import selenium 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.legeropinion.com/app/todo")

email_element = browser.find_element_by_id("email")
email_element.clear()
email_element.send_keys("something@gmail.com")

password_element = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
password_element.send_keys("password")

sign_in = browser.find_element_by_class_name("submit-btn").click()

select_survey = browser.find_element_by_class_name("ng-star-inserted").click()
```

I am trying to automate signing into a website and completing a form but upon clicking on the form for which the element is class = ng-star-inserted i am getting that error

edit:

this is the relevant html info i believe:

```
<task-block _ngcontent-buv-c2="" _nghost-buv-c9="" class="ng-star-inserted"><!----><div _ngcontent-buv-c9="" class="task ng-star-inserted"><!----><a _ngcontent-buv-c9=""
```

Comment: Could you please share the html body of the element you are referring to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after some a lot of trial and error I finally got it to work by fluke. I don't know how but it worked!!

I simply located the element by the ABSOLUTE xpath which I copied from the HTML and then before that line i had the time sleep function like so:

```
time.sleep(2)
select_survey = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/ion-app/ion-         router-outlet/app-todo/ion-content/mat-expansion-panel[1]/div/div/div[2]/task-block[2] /div").click()
```

Comment: i know the absolute path creates technical debt, but it was the only solution that worked for me. if anyone knows how this magically worked and the other suggestions did not, please feel free to share!